# WebService Security between DMZ - Protected Network

Tags: security, authentication, asmx

I have a custom desktop application which invokes an ASMX web service. The Service is hosted under a SharePoint Site in a Virtual Directory in IIS. The authentication used is Windows Integrated.

Now, I want to use the same application from a host in our DMZ. I configured ISA Server to allow HTTP access from the DMZ to the Server in our protected network.

Trying to test the application I got some errors like: "Client found response Content type text/html but expected text/xml". I guess that this error comes from the authentication failure since the same app works fine in the protected mode.

What are my options here concerning authentication? Should I allow Anonymous?

Thanks,
Dimitris.

Comment: Is it fair to suggest that the problem happens only if the authentication mode is no longer Windows integrated  - since the host is not in the Intranet and moved over to the DMZ. Is that the issue?

Comment: That "text/html" response is probably an error message. Read it and see who is telling you what.

Comment: I tried to grab the output and view and it seems it is an HTML message: **<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>-1073740781(0xc0000413)<body/></html>**. This means STATUS_AUTHENTICATION_FIREWALL_FAILED (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx). <br/>After changing the credentials of the Web Service from DefaultCredentials to an account existing in the domain hosting the Service (protected network) it worked fine. <br/> Which is the best practice of Authenticating the user?Should I add a corporate account to my code to authenticate? Should I enable Anonymous Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution!
I had to provide to all the DMZ Domain users that would access the Web Service "Allowed to Authenticate" Permission under Active Directory WFE's computer account